# Is my Facebook canvas app displaying the login dialog?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-oauth

Is my Facebook canvas app displaying the login dialog automatically upon arrival? I want it to butI have been fighting this for quite some time. I have Page Tab Apps that feed off of the same canvas URL and these are indeed displaying the login dialog for the app automatically in in a pop-up.
 I clear my browsers cookies when I test.
 I am using Javascript and the Facebook SDK to build my app with a GoDaddy Website Builder; can I use PHP with this website builder?

My app- [https://apps.facebook.com/{My_App}/](https://apps.facebook.com/emoticon_app_x/)

*Code in HEAD section*

```
   <meta property="og:type" content="emoticon_app_x:app">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{My App ID}">
<meta property="og:title" content="Emoticon App. X">
<meta property="og:description" content="Easy to use copy and paste emoticons for     Facebook.">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://apps.facebook.com/{My_App}">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://nebula.wsimg.com/b270c0b24507a5a9018ec56c54957962?AccessKeyId=E136FD740FAB2A181ED3&amp;disposition=0&amp;alloworigin=1">
<meta name="google-translate-customization" content="c7ecf59b1c239b7f-e83518b06897476f-g415c0e55e9c88e54-17">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '{My App ID}',
          status     : true,
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.0'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    console.log('Logged in.');
  }
  else {
    FB.login();
  }
});
</script>
```

*end HEAD section code*

*Code in BODY section*

```
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '{My App ID',
          status     : true,
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.0'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    console.log('Logged in.');
  }
  else {
    FB.login();
  }
});
</script>
    <body>"<"!--   Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses the    JavaScript SDK to   present a graphical Login button that
 triggers the FB.login() function when clicked. --">"
<p><fb:login-button show-faces="false" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button></p></body>
</html>
```

*end BODY section code*

Comment: Neither canvas nor page tab apps will ask for login automatically – unless you explicitly trigger it from your code, or your canvas app is accessed from App Center and you have configured permissions to ask for in that case in your app dashboard.

Comment: I am explicitly asking for automatic login, I _think_ . @CBroe .? Can you see a problem with my code?

Comment: Why that is not working for the app you linked to above, you browser’s error console will tell you.

Comment: Thank you for your time @CBroe. I will start digging there. FYI here are the errors                                                        **        Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined www.emoticon-app-x.com/?fb_source=bookmark&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=2_0:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined www.emoticon-app-x.com/?fb_source=bookmark&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=2_0:768
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null www.emoticon-app-x.com/?fb_source=bookmark&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=2_0:782
**

Comment: `FB is not defined` – and that happens because you’re trying to call `FB.getLoginStatus` before the SDK has finished loading & initializing, and since your `FB.login` call is nested into that … nothing happens at all in regard to login. Move that code inside the `window.fbAsyncInit` event handler function.